# How to use phpMyAdmin with Amazon RDS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I am trying to use Amazon for the first time. I have created a database instance and it is up and running. I want use this database. I tried it using terminal in my mac by following command:
`mysql -h xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p`

But I am getting error as following:

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

How can I connect to database from here and also how should I access it from phpMyAdmin. I have all the details about the database but I am not sure about how to get url for phpMyAdmin.

Comment: try without the "-P 3306" and -p enter the password, does it still not work ?.. is this question closed ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have made security group to allow access from outside of AWS for port 3306.